# Is this possible to set cron job without cpanel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cron, setinterval

I have a add_post form to add new post which include post title, content, description and post_date_n_time.

If the post_date is current date or past date then post stored in database as publish and if post_date_n_time is future date then post stores in database as draft. If the post date is future date then I stored post_id and post_date in post_schedule table as follows-

post_schedule table

```
post_id |  post_date  
   1    |  2017-03-04 19:01:00
   2    |  2017-03-04 19:30:00
   3    |  2017-12-15 16:01:00
```

I want to set cronjob as per post_date and time stored in database table post_schedule, so that I would be able to update post_status draft to publish. can I use setInterval method to achieve what I want that pass the post_date to setInterval method, so that it would fired as per specified date.

Comment: what has cron got to do with javascript?

Comment: i think you don't know what server/client side mean

Comment: @madalin I am asking about alternative for cronjob. using setInterval method php page can be accesssed where I can perform what I want

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Cron Job for that.

```
function getIsDraft($item) {
    // if timestamp of item post_date is lower than return TRUE - is draft
    // else return FALSE - is published
    return strtotime($item->post_date) > time();
}
```